# How use a variable in switch regexp

Tags: regex, switch-statement, tcl

I have a problem using a variable as a pattern in the `switch` command with option `-regexp`.

For example:

```
namespace eval ::foo {
    variable symbols {[-=*+_=$!.\w]}
}

proc ::foo::bar {c} {
    variable symbols
    switch -regexp $c {
       {\(} {
           return "("
       }
       ...
       $symbols {
           ungetc $c
           return [consume_number_or_symbol]
       }
       ...  
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work, but putting the regular expression directly `{[-=*+_=$!.\w]}` instead of `$symbol` works.

How can be used a variable in `switch` with `regexp` options?

Comment: It doesn't look as pretty, but you can use `list` as in [this example](http://codepad.org/GMKX2ugG). Which means that substitution of the pattern is not performed in the `switch` body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a single last argument, you can pass several `pattern body` pairs; see the documentation of [`switch`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/switch.html) for more. Just be sure to continue the command appropriately with backslashes, and use `--` to mark the end of options (in case `$c` begins with a hyphen):

```
proc ::foo::bar {c} {
    variable symbols
    switch -regexp -- $c \
       {\(} {
           return "("
       }              \
       $symbols {
           ungetc $c
           return [consume_number_or_symbol]
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $symbol is not expanded as is sits inside {}. The below code works:

```
proc foo {c} {
set symbols x
switch -regexp $c \
    $symbols    { puts "1" } \
    x           { puts "2" } \
```

}
foo x